# Cascading DropDownLists

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, list, cascadingdropdown

For my application, i need to incorporate some dropdownlists in order to display some table in function of the differents values selected in these lists.
But when I select a value in one list, an other fills in function of the value and I don't know how to do that.

In my application, I only use Raw queries like that :

```
        string requeteAppli ="select distinct CD_APPLI, ORDRE_APPLI from dbo.REF_APPLI where CD_APPLI != 'PNB' order by ORDRE_APPLI";
```

With a function for execute them like that :

```
public List<DataRow> executerRequete(string query)
    {
        //Initialisation d'une variable Liste contenant des lignes de données où seront récupérés les résultats de la requête suivante.
        List<DataRow> liste = null;

        //Création d'une variable de connection où sont stockés toutes les informations nécessaires à la connexion à la base de données.
        //Ces informations sont stockées dans le fichier de config Web.config.
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["REF_ConnectionString"];

        //Création d'un objet instance de SqlConnection (classe permettant la connexion ouverte à une base de données) où est stocké le contenu de la variable connString.
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            //Création d'un objet de commande permettant de spécifier comment la commande sera inteprétée, ici en commande de texte SQL avec CommandType.Text.
            using (SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                //Création d'un objet de commande permettant de spécifier comment la commande sera inteprétée, ici en commande de texte SQL avec CommandType.Text.
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //Création d'un objet instance de DataTable qui va récupérer la résultat de la requête.
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //Création d'un objet instance de SqlDataAdapter qui va effectuer le lien avec SQL Server afin de récupérer les données.
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
                //Ouverture de la connexion.
                conn.Open();
                //L'instruction FILL récupère les données de la source de données et les insère dans dt.
                adp.Fill(dt);
                //Vérification du contenu de dt.
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    //Remplissage de la liste.
                    liste = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        //Le résultat est retournée à l'action.
        return liste;
    }
```

The problem is with these queries, I've seen a lot of tutorials of how implement cascading dropdownlists with ASP.NET MVC and jQuery but it wasn't with this style of queries and I'm totally confused with them and I can't change them.

I get the result of these queries in my actions like that :

```
var queries = new query();
var items = rq.executerRequete(requeteIndex);
queries.Query2 = (from i in items2
                  select new Suivi { CD_APPLI = i.Field<String>("CD_APPLI") }).ToList();
```

My goal is to have a first list of Applications and when the user select one value an other list containing some date (depend of the application selected) fills in function.
Here is the query which get the dates in function of the selected application :

```
var itemsDate = rq.executerRequete(requetePERIODE);
var periode = (from i in itemsDate
               where i.Field<String>("CD_APPLI").Trim() == appli.Trim()
               select new Suivi { PERIODE = i.Field<Int64>("PERIODE") });
```

I'm totally lost with these cascading dropdownlists and I really need your help :/
If you need code, i can give you this but even if i've tried some solutions for these lists, I can't give you an example of my code (javascript) because it doesn't work at all and i do anything, my code is simply a lot of bullshit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

serverside
you fill the application dropdown with application id's and something to display

clientside
you'll want to attach a function on the change event of your first dropdown list
to fetch the data and fill the dates dropdown
like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#CboApplications').change(function() {
      function getDates() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Reg_Form.aspx/GetDates",
          data: "{'applicationId':" + ( $('#CboApplications').val()) + "}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          global: false,
          async: false,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(jsonObj) {
             for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.Table.length; i++){
               listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonObj.Table[i].PERIODE+ "'>" + jsonObj.Table[i].PERIODE+ "</option>";
              }
             $("#cboDates").html(listItems);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
    });
```

to get the data you will need a web method or a web service with a web method that executes your query code

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Sub GetDates(ByVal applicationId As String)
    //use correct qry based on applicationId 
    var itemsDate = rq.executerRequete(requetePERIODE);
    var periode = (from i in itemsDate
           where i.Field<String>("CD_APPLI").Trim() == appli.Trim()
           select new Suivi { PERIODE = i.Field<Int64>("PERIODE") });
    Return periode 
End Sub
```

this code wil not be 100% correct as i cant test it myself atm but the concept might help you

example webmethod in a page (important are static, WebMethod and ScriptMethod for ajax calls)

```
public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page 

   { 
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()] 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
    public static List<Product> GetProducts(int cateogryID) 
    {
      // Put your logic here to get the Product list 
    }
```

Comment: vous pourriez peut-être essayer de formuler votre question autrement.

Comment: Ok ok mais en Anglais :D So, I have 2 dropdownlists : one which is a list of Application and an other which is a list of date. What I want is to fill the second list (list of date) in function of the selected value in the first list (list of applications) with jQuery and the raw queries. To do this, I think the way to go is when I select a value in the first list, an action get the value selected and fills the second list with the data corresponding. Is it clear ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But just one thing, I have never used a web method so I don't know where to put this into my code :/ Do I have to create a Web Service file (.asmx) and include this method in this file ?

Comment: you can put it in your page.aspx.cs(vb) or in a seperate .asmx (could be easier to group all logic for 1 page in that page) ill edit to add an example

Comment: Oops, I didn't see your answer before to post my other question, I was writing it... I will try it but could you check my other question please ? And thanks for you help !!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah !!! It works !!

The problem was with the query which get the result of the second list, I had to do that :

```
var periode = (from i in itemsDate
                       where i.Field<String>("CD_APPLI").Trim() == appli.Trim()
                       select new { value = i.Field<Int64>("PERIODE").ToString(), text = i.Field<Int64>("PERIODE").ToString() });
```

And not that :

```
            var periode = (from i in itemsDate
                       where i.Field<String>("CD_APPLI").Trim() == appli.Trim()
                       select new SelectListItem { Value = i.Field<Int64>("PERIODE").ToString(), Text = i.Field<Int64>("PERIODE").ToString() });
```

The rest of my code doesn't change relative to the second answer.

Now I'll try with a third list and if I have others problems, I'll get back here.

Really thanks for your help, ufosnowcat :D

Comment: you are welcome, so you had to use an anonimous object versus a selectlistitem pff didn't know that :p stackoverflow debugging ;)

Comment: I've forgot to ask one thing, do you know how can I get the values selected in two dropdown lists in order to fills a third list in javascript ? Can I do a thing like that : `$('#List1', '#List2').change(function() ? I don't think so but I'm a true beginner in javascript so why not :D

Comment: you can bind to the change function of multiple elements at once using jquery selectors (have a look here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) one of the easyest is a class selector $('.ListesDiaboliques').change(... and then apply the cssclass ListesDiaboliques to all the dropdowns you want to bind. But do you want this? the function that is called will be the same for all of them, usually leading to more complex functions to take all possibilities into account and more errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, i'll try it but I've a little problem, actually I have 4 lists, when I select a value in the third list, the fourth fills automatically and correctly but when I have juste one value in my third list, I can't select it and the fourth list doesn't fills at all. What can I do ? Define a default value or an empty value which will be in the list anytime? But how can I dot that ?

Comment: i'm going to start a new answer the comments are driving me nuts ;)

Answer (score 0):

as answer to the last comment

adding a please select would be 1 way to go; 
in your return function for the data of your 3d list insert on position 0 a value 'please select' forcing the user to trigger the action

an other option would be:
1) put the logic you now call in the .change function in a seperate function that way it is easier to call from several places

then where you bind the change function after you fill your current(3d) list check if there is only 1 item in the list 
if so call the function to fill the 4th list you could integrate this in the filling of each list:
after the

```
$.each(months, function (index, periode) {... }));
```

put something like (check what you can do with period)

```
if (periode.count() == 1) {fillnextList();};
```

Comment: Add this doesn't change anything :/ I've find a little solution to correct this, I've just add a value like this : "--- Appli ---" then I can select the only real value in the list.